# How can I open the printing menu with a button in tkinter?

Tags: tkinter, printing

I want to open a printing menu by pressing a button in tkinter. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: That's a difficult question to answer, especially without knowing what system you're on. It may be more complicated than just calling out to some dialog. Again, it depends on what system you're using.

Comment: I don't quite get by what you say to be a system. If I am not misunderstanding you, I am using Windows 11 and would like to make the button open the standard Windows printing menu. Although, thank you for your concern. In case you come across any info on this topic, please notify.

Comment: Okay, here's something. It looks like the code in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60535407/16775594) seems to use the [`wxPython`](https://pypi.org/project/wxPython/#description) module, which apparently contains printer-window related stuff. Beyond that, I don't really know much, since I don't use Windows or `wxPython`, but that should put you on the right track. I also don't know if `wxPython` uses the standard print window or not. By the way, I suggest that you read about [ask]. Your question as it stands doesn't meet SO guidelines. Good questions should show a [mre] and research.